# App crashes when headset is disconnected -- App(service) gets restarted

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, headset

App crashes when headset is disconnected

I am trying following code

```
     private int headsetSwitch = 1; 
     registerReceiver(headsetReciever, new IntentFilter(
             Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG));

public BroadcastReceiver headsetReciever = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public boolean headsetconnected = false;

     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

     if (intent.hasExtra("state")) {
     if (headsetconnected && intent.getIntExtra("state", 0) == 0) {
     headsetconnected = false;
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "headsetconnected = false",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     headsetSwitch = 0;
     }

     else if (!headsetconnected
     && intent.getIntExtra("state", 0) == 1) {
     headsetconnected = true;
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "headsetconnected = true",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     headsetSwitch = 1;
     // Lockscreencontrol();
     }

     }

     switch (headsetSwitch) {
     case (0):
     headsetDisconnected();
     break;
     case (1):
     break;
     }
     }

     };

     private void headsetDisconnected() {
     try {
    if(mMediaplayer.isplaying()) 
      mMediaplayer.pause();

      }


     } catch (Exception e) {
     // TODO: handle exception
     }

     }
```

Above code works perfectly fine if I have my app running (which is either minimized or we are currently viewing some activity from teh app) now when I would disconnect the headset the mediaplayer would pause which is the expected result.

The app is based on a service.

Now when I swipe away the app , the service is running in The background , when I disconnected the Headset, the app crashes.

For detecting the app has been swiped away  I tried to unregister the broadcast receiver  but still the app would crash

The code used to detect that app has been closed using following code

```
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
            unregisterReceiver(headsetReciever);

    }
```

Unfortunately I do not have any log to share any help would be great.

----------------update-------------

after being able to generate a logcat from actual device

I am able to generate following errorlog

`E/MUSIC PLAYER( 4110): castconnected:false mApiClientnull mRemoteMediaPlayernull`

and more specifically

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 4183): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 4183): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com
.musicplayer.mp3player.PlayService@41741a10 with null: java.lang.NullPointerExce
ption
 E/AndroidRuntime( 4183): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime( 4183): at .PlayService.onStart
Command(PlayService.java:233)
```

now I have two options either

1) stop the service from being restarted
2) disable the check of headset removal when app is swiped away

how can any one of the above can be done

Comment: Please post the stacktrace/logcat.

Comment: unfortunately  there is no way to test headset on emulator , or is there any please guide me on that, then I will be able to post the logcat. I am testing on a lenovo A7000  device .

Comment: updated the question with error log please check and help if possible.

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you don't have OnTaskRemoved() method.try removing this method.It would be more helpful if you put the log.which aide are you using?